# determine colour of bars in vba

Tags: excel, vba

is there a possibility in VBA to control the colour of each individual 3D bar in a 3D histogram (such as here) 
[image]

I would like to pass it a colour matrix with as many entries as there are bars specifying the colour of each bar seperately (in rgb or another colour code). Is that possible without doing it manually? As the height of the bar is not related to the colour it should get, conditional formatting does not really solve the problem. The matrix is 20 by 20 so doing it by hand is very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim cht As Chart, s As Long, p As Long
Dim ser As Series, arr, rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G10") 'for example
    arr = rng.Value 

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

    For s = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(s)
        For p = 1 To ser.Points.Count

            'assigning from array
            ser.Points(p).Interior.Color = arr(s, p)

            'assigning from worksheet cell
            'ser.Points(p).Interior.Color = rng.Cells(s, p).Interior.Color

        Next p
    Next

End Sub
```

You can feed in a 2-D array of RGB values which you can index into using `s` and `p`
That array could be read from the worksheet (as in the example) or come from some other source.

Comment: could you maybe show a small example how I create such an arrey? Would I just use ser.Points(p).Interior.Color=mat[s,p] - where each entry in the matrix is an rgb? as in RGB(100,100,100)?

Comment: hey...can you tell me how the colour has to be indicated in the matrix? As rgb(100,100,100) or "rgb(100,100,100) or [rgb,100,100,100]............?Or would I need to set it as background colour of the cell..that would be very tedious

Comment: If you're going to read it from a cell then you'd need to put the RGB value as a single number. Enter `? RGB(100,100,100)` in the Immediate window and hit Enter: it will show you the value you need. It's difficult to suggest the "best" approach without knowing exactly how you're determining what those numbers should be.

Comment: which ways are there? can i also set the colour as background in the cell (that would be very important to know)..how would i then need to modify the code to read that in? This might be a new question but can I parse the colour code out of an image in the worksheet? I have a heatmap and would like to colour each bar according to the colour of the heatmap